# Как удалить элементы из двумерного массива?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Как удалить элементы из двумерного массива, `exersise.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)` работает не постоянно, переодически падает и выдает ошибку `fatal error: Array index out of range`

```
import UIKit

var exersise = [(name: String, image:String, checked: Bool)]()

class AllExersiseTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    struct Objects {
        var sectionName: String!
        var sectionObjects: [(name: String, image:String, checked: Bool)]!
    }

    var objectsArray = [Objects]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        objectsArray = [
            Objects(sectionName: "Standing", sectionObjects: [(name: "Приседания", image:"bb", checked: false)]),
            Objects(sectionName: "Sitting", sectionObjects: [(name: "БЕГ", image:"ru", checked: false)]),
            Objects(sectionName: "Special", sectionObjects: [(name: "БЕГ", image:"ru", checked: false)])]
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return objectsArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return objectsArray[section].sectionObjects.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        if cell!.accessoryType == .None {
            cell!.accessoryType = .Checkmark
            self.objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row].checked = true
            exersise.append(objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]) //добавляем в массив элементы ячейки 
        } else {
            cell!.accessoryType = .None
            self.objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row].checked = false
           exersise.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row) //Удаляем добавленные элементы из массива. Не работает, приложение падает fatal error: Array index out of range
        }
        print(exersise)
        print(exersise.count)
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row].name
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row].image)
        cell.accessoryType = self.objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row].checked ? .Checkmark : .None
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?{
        return objectsArray[section].sectionName
    }

    func indexPathsForSelectedRowsInSection(section: Int) -> [NSIndexPath]? {
        return (tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows!).filter({ (indexPath) -> Bool in
            indexPath.section == section
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: а можно пример, который сразу скомпилируется?

Comment: Это весь файл для компиляции

Comment: как минимум у меня нет доступа к вашему сториборду. когда вы писали комментарий `//and other` туда же попало несколько скобок. последняя закрытая скобка внизу не попала в снипет.

Comment: Подправил немного, в сториборде кастомная ячейка с идентификатором Cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас проблема в методе `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`.

Сначала туда последовательно добавляются элементы и размер массива растет:

```
exersise.append(objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row])
```

При повторном нажатии они удаляются, но неправильно - в качестве индекса вы берете индекс ячейки в таблице:

```
exersise.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
```

Таким образом, если выделить первую и пятую ячейку, то в массиве будет только два элемента. Если повторно нажать на пятую ячейку, произойдет попытка удалить из массива пятый элемент, а там их всего два.

Я предлагаю модифицировать код метода примерно так:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) else { return } // убеждаемся, что ячейка правильная

    var object = objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]
    if object.checked {
        cell.accessoryType = .None
        object.checked = false
        if let index = exersise.indexOf(object) { // находим реальный индекс объекта в массиве
            exersise.removeAtIndex(index) // удаляем объект по правильному индексу
        }
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        object.checked = true
        exersise.append(object) //добавляем в массив элементы ячейки
    }
}
```

Однако, теперь будет ошибка, что нельзя получить индекс элемента массива, т.к. это tuple. От неё можно избавиться, превратив tuple в полноценный класс:

```
class Exersise: Equatable { // Протокол Equatable говорит о том, что объекты можно сравнивать. Это нужно для поиска элемента в массиве.
    var name: String
    var image: String
    var checked: Bool

    init(name: String, image: String, checked: Bool) {
        self.name = name
        self.image = image
        self.checked = checked
    }
}

// Эта функция обязательно должна быть глобальной и требуется протоколом Equatable, без неё компилятор будет ругаться, что структура не соответствует протоколу.
func ==(lhs: Exersise, rhs: Exersise) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.image == rhs.image
}

var exersise = [Exersise]() // заменяем tuple на класс

class AllExersiseTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    struct Objects {
        var sectionName: String!
        var sectionObjects: [Exersise]! // И здесь тоже. А зачем "!"?
    }

    var objectsArray = [Objects]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Здесь всё осталось примерно так же, только добавилось имя класса для вызова инициализатора
        objectsArray = [
            Objects(sectionName: "Standing", sectionObjects: [Exersise(name: "Приседания", image: "bb", checked: false)]),
            Objects(sectionName: "Sitting", sectionObjects: [Exersise(name: "БЕГ", image:"ru", checked: false)]),
            Objects(sectionName: "Special", sectionObjects: [Exersise(name: "БЕГ", image:"ru", checked: false)])]
    }

    ...
}
```

В таком виде всё должно работать.

Ещё я предлагаю модифицировать код метода создания ячейки следующим образом:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let object = objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = object.name
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: object.image)
    cell.accessoryType = object.checked ? .Checkmark : .None
    return cell
}
```

Выделение объекта в отдельную переменную облегчает понимание сути происходящего и резко снижает вероятность ошибки.

Comment: Появилась проблема, отмеченные чекмаркнром ячейки при проматывании таблицы и возвращении к отмеченным ячейкам чекмаркер исчезает...

Comment: Да, там некорректная проверка на выделение, я сразу не заметил. Через пару часов до дома доберусь, поправлю. Идея в том, что надо не отметку в ячейке проверять, т.к. ячейки переиспользуются, а поле соответствующего объекта.

Comment: Андрей, к сожалению исчезание чекмаркера так и не устранено... Еще такой вопрос от новичка, теперь exersise можно передать и сохранить на другом контроллере через NSUserDefaults или все таки надо делать через CoreDate ?

Comment: .еще добавилось то что уже установленный чекмаркер теперь не снимается при повторном нажатии на ячейку и в массив снова добавляются объекты этой ячейки, а не удаляются.

Comment: Лучше просто передать его другому контроллеру напрямую, через присваивание переменной. NSUserDefaults и CoreData для этого слишком тяжелые инструменты.

Comment: Даже если это будет несколько вариантов exersise, переданных на др контроллер в разные ячейки таблицы с разными наборами обжектов?

Comment: Не уверен, что понял идею. Но NSUserDefaults используется обычно для сохранения состояния между запусками приложения, например, сохранения настроек. CoreData хорошо подходит для сохранения больших объемов динамических данных с известной структурой (загрузка из интернета, например). Для передачи между контроллерами лучше использовать более простые способы, т.к. там не будет потерь производительности на ненужных сохранениях данных  в файл.

Comment: Увидел, в чем проблема. Дело в том, что структуры при вытаскивании объекта из массива копируются, так что изменения в них не сохраняются. Так что вместо структуры Exersise нужно использовать класс. Обновил свой ответ, теперь всё точно работает как надо :)

Comment: Андрей, все работает, без сбоев... Единственный момент при выводе на экран print(exersise) по нажатию на ячейку выдает [GuyFit.Exersise],по нажатию на след ячейку [GuyFit.Exersise, GuyFit.Exersise], а раньше выдавало еще и значение Exersise т.е. выводило пример [GuyFit.Exersise(name: "Приседания", image: "bb", checked: true)]. Это не влияет на передачу этих значений, или все таки exersise не показывает теперь значения и это ошибка?

Comment: Нет, не повлияет. Эта строчка там вообще не нужна. Классы отличаются от структур и перечислений, поэтому компилятор не знает как автоматически показать содержимое и показывает только имя класса объекта. Но сами данные лежат в объекте и доступны, просто для их отображения в print нужно сделать дополнительные действия.

Comment: Андрей, спасибо большое за потраченное время и помощь

Comment: Лучшая благодарность - это принятый ответ :)